# SQL JOIN QUERY with more than one items in common: Find the franchise pairs that operate together in more than one location

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called dfmt that lists the location, revenue and franchise. I want to find the franchise pairs that operate together in more than one location.

[image: Some sample data]

So far, I have a query that finds the franchise pairs that operate in the same location:

```
select T1.fr, T2.fr2 from dfmt T1 join (select fr as fr2, loc as loc2 from dfmt) as T2 on T1.fr < T2.fr2 and T1.loc = T2.loc2 order by loc;
```

I do not know how to go from here to find the franchise pairs that operate together in only more than one location.

Another query that may be useful that Finds the franchise that generates the maximum revenue in more than one location.

```
select fr, count(*) from tst2 where rev in (select max(rev) from tst2 group by loc) group by fr having count(*)>1;
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi @anon - not sure what the R has to do with it - perhaps remove it from the question and put in some sample data..

Comment: Yes, I deleted it and put some sample data, please look at it again if you can help

Comment: "I do not know how to go from here" So the current code doesn't do yet what you want it to do? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - use group by to gather all the "franchise pairs" and you count how many have locations..

```sql
SELECT X.fr, X.fr2, COUNT(X.loc) as count FROM 
(
  select T1.fr, T2.fr2, T1.loc from dfmt T1 join (select fr as fr2, loc as loc2 from dfmt) as T2 on T1.fr < T2.fr2 and T1.loc = T2.loc2
) AS X GROUP BY fr, fr2 HAVING count > 1;
```

NOTE: This relies on the inner query having distinct results - ie.. you can't have say "Best Western" and "Raddison" twice for the same location.

Comment: I recieve an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'loc' in 'field list'

Comment: @anon I didn't look closely enough at your query (which I've used as a sub-query) to see it didn't have loc in the result [that data you show isn't the result of it !!].  I'll update the answer with that - however you may need to cater for DB differences ...

Comment: @anon ie. if your DB doesn't support _HAVING_ - drop it and then do as another sub-query with a `WHERE count > 1`